# angular2/ typescript convert string into an array

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typescript, angular

```
JSON.stringify(this.p)
console.log(this.p + " " + typeof(this.p))
```

These statements give me

```
[{lat:52.52193980072258,lng:13.401432037353516},{lat:52.52319316685915,lng:13.407096862792969},{lat:52.51969409696076,lng:13.407225608825684}] string
```

So `this.p` is a string. If I use it to draw a polygon in my google map, it gives not an Array exception (but natural!).

How can I convert it to an array (of type perhaps google.maps.LatLngLiteral or any suitable one)?

**Note**: If I do after `JSON.stringify(this.p)`:

```
JSON.parse(this.p)
console.log(this.p + " " + typeof( this.p))
```

this says: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 2`

**What's going wrong and how can I fix it?**

I use it like this in my polygon:

```
 var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: this.p,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: this.map
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete method looks like following:

```
var myVar=[]

    this.exhibitionSurveyObjectService.getObjects()
    .subscribe(

      response => {       

        this.exhibitionSurveyObjects = response;
        console.log(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects)

        for(var i = 0; i < this.exhibitionSurveyObjects.length; i++){

          myVar.push(JSON.parse(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path)) 

        }

        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: myVar,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: this.map
        });
      },

      error =>  {
        console.log("error")
        this.errorMessage = <any>error; 

      }

      )
```

Comment: What is the result of your `this.exhibitionSurveyObjectService.getObjects()` method?

Comment: console.log(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[0].path) gives me: [{"lat":52.52157422886321,"lng":13.400187492370605},{"lat":52.5232715010553,"lng":13.407654762268066},{"lat":52.52068639882502,"lng":13.4067964553833}] , without .path it gives me object with several attributes

Comment: Ok, so it looks like normal js object (not a string), why you are trying to do `JSON.parse(this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path)`?

Comment: Because this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path is a string and I can not use it  to assign it to paths of polygon

Comment: And you have the error right in this line (during `JSON.parse`)?

Comment: Yes correct! It said 'unexpected charachter l' i.e. l from lat

Comment: So, it only means, that your string is not a properly JSON formatted string or it is not a string at all..
Usually, it happens when someone trying to pass into `JSON.parse()` an object... Can you check the real value of `this.exhibitionSurveyObjects[i].path` in debugger (not using `console.log`) please?

Comment: I ran into multiple confusions because the code I referred to was applying .replace function to remove double quotes from "lat" and "lang" and then parsing the whole string. This was wrong actually. I tried JSON.Stringify and then parsing it etc as well in different orders.

Comment: Oh.. using '.replace function to remove double quotes' - is a very bad practice, that's why you've got errors, try to avoid it for a formatted JSON strings, only using `JSON.parse()`